Error display drivers "not connecting"
я хочу подключить 2-й внешный экран с адаптером вга на узб3,0 но не могу найти тот драйвер чтобы добавить в част настройки экрана как его решить помаги мне пожалуйстаenter image description here

Sorry English only site.
